# fabric command in local context is failing grep command

Tags: python, docker, fabric

I'm on OS X using boot2docker. I'm trying to use fabric to simplify running docker containers for our QA's.

Running this command...

```
  containerFound = fab.local('docker ps -a | grep nodejs', capture=True)
  # this didn't work either if fab.local('docker ps -a | grep nodejs').succeeded
```

generates the following error:

```
Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'docker ps -a | grep nodejs'
```

Is this an issue using boot2docker. I tried using sudo as well but nothing. I believe boot2docker runs as root anyways so sudo isn't needed.

Comment: If you are trying to orchestrate local containers for testing I would recommend you fig.

Comment: Thanks @JavierCastellanos I was going to look into fig but we need it to run in Windows too and fig doesn't do Windows from what I've read

Comment: But wait...theres is a workaround for Windows https://github.com/docker/fig/issues/598

Answer (score 1):

In Fabric 1.3.2 at least, you can recover the exception by catching the SystemExit exception. That's helpful if you have more than one command to run in a batch (like a deploy) and want to cleanup if one of them fails.